# TapGestureRecgonizer on UIImage not working in a Storyboard setup

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I've set my UIImage to recognise taps by linking its GestureRecognizers to a Tap Gesture Recognizer.

[image]

The Tap Gesture Recogniser should then trigger a method in my class.

[image]

The IBAction method never gets triggered, What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Interaction for the UIImage must be enabled!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to set UserInteractionEnabled of uiimage true .

```
[UImage setUserInteractionEnable:YES];
```

Comment: It should be noted he likely meant UIImageView; not UIImage (could cause some confusion).